# WPF layout control which would arrange its children using a down-then-across flow

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am looking for a WPF layout control which would arrange its children using a down-then-across flow as illustrated below:
[image]

The above example uses 2 columns. The number of rows results from rows = round(items/columns).

With a different number of items, the layout would be as follows:
[image]

Items shall be stretched horizontally to fill their space. The total height of the entire panel depends on the height of the elements.
In case items have different heights, the corresponding "row" shall be stretched to match the highest element:
[image]

Ultimately, this would be the ItemsPanel for an ItemsControl or even a ListBox.

I have not been able to find a standard WPF panel that would do this and would therefore appreciate any help.

Comment: [How to: Create a Custom Panel Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: If you can't live without the row height constraint i.e. accept even row height distribution you can use a vertically oriented WrapPanel.

Comment: You can also modify the DataGrid template or use a ListView without headers. You would have to design your data structures based on rows. Your view requirement is essentially a table with rows and columns where a row shared the same height.